# External jar class not found while run time in Spring boot (Maven)

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, maven-plugin, executable-jar

I am getting classNotFound while running the jar. This class is present in external jar which was added through build path. Before I got compile time error so I added following code in pom.xml. So Now I am not getting compile time error but now I am getting error while run that executable jar.

I read other article also as per them some time external jar file path not found at run time so we need to java classpath (Source attachment). So I added through Build path > jar > added source attachment. But Still it that class not found at run time.

Pom.xml

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>spring-boot</classifier>
                            <mainClass>
                                com.main.Application
                            </mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Error Page :

[image: Error Page]

Comment: That may happen when you have dependencies conflicts. Have you checked that?

Comment: Yes, I have checked I have only one jar.

Comment: But is this jar also a Maven dependency?

Comment: No. I added through only Build path.

Comment: What do you mean by `I added through only Build path`? Added as a dependency in your pom file? Apart from that the screen shot is more or less unreadable. Please post a text message here not images...

Answer (score 1):

It solved my issue after added my external jar in maven dependency.

Steps :

1. create libs folder in your project. Right click on project > New > Folder > libs
2. Put your external jar file in that folder.
3. Open pom.xml file and add that dependency into your code.

Name of jar : ReleaseVersion.jar

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ReleaseVersion</groupId>
        <artifactId>ReleaseVersion</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/ReleaseVersion.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

By using this steps I solved my issue.

Comment: This is working. Thank you. Can you elaborate on the reason?